# Why do I get a segmentation fault when running an example program compiled without cmake? (MSYS2, Mingw-w64)

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, mingw-w64, msys2

### In short

What are cmake's web of makefiles doing differently from a simple compile and link that is making a difference in the final executable?

I'm trying to use the bullet physics library (bullet3-2.83.7) https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3.  
I compiled the library okay with few warnings in MSYS2 with Mingw-w64.  
Afterwards I can run the example programs without problems, specifically ExampleBrowser and HelloWorld.  
I've been trying to incorporate the HelloWorld source into a test project using just a Makefile but I get SIGSEGV errors whenever there is a call to dynamicsWorld in the executable.  The SEGFAULT occurs at lines `dynamicsWorld->AddRigidBody(body);` or if those are commented out `dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation` 
This occurs with the exact example source file compiled with the makefile (source not modified).

 
gdb tells me this

```
main (argc=1, argv=0x5f4eb0) at main.cpp:78
78                      dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(body);
(gdb) step
0x0000000000002000 in ?? ()
(gdb) step
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x0000000000002000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I don't know what to do with this info.  I assume/hope I'm just missing a compiler or linker flag? 
My original Makefile is a big mess based off http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation.  I assumed it would be enough to just use the existing makefile on the example code by adding the libraries and include directory `-lBulletDynamics_Debug -lBulletCollision_Debug -lLinearMath_Debug`

I've also tried a simplified Makefile with commands and flags I found grepping the CMake directories from bullet3/examples/HelloWorld. 
 
My PATH environment variable is clean, nothing in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (In MSYS: echo $PATH)

```
MSYS2 Mingw-w64
gcc 10.1.0
MSYS 20180531msys64 ? pacman updated a lot of things
CMake 3.17.3
GNU Make 4.3
```

### Makefile

```
CXX_DEFINES = -DUSE_GRAPHICAL_BENCHMARK -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 

CXX_INCLUDES = -I"C:\lib64\include\bullet3"
CXX_FLAGS = -g -fpermissive -D_DEBUG 

.PHONY: all
all:
    g++.exe $(CXX_DEFINES) $(CXX_INCLUDES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o main.obj -c main.cpp
    ar cr main.a main.obj
    g++.exe $(CXX_FLAGS) -Wl,--whole-archive main.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o bulletTest.exe -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 libBulletDynamics_Debug.a libBulletCollision_Debug.a libLinearMath_Debug.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32

# -L"C:\lib64\lib" 

.PHONY: run
run:
    gdb -ex run bulletTest.exe -ex "bt full" -ex quit --batch

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f ./bulletTest.exe ./main.obj ./main.a
```

## Building the bullet physics library in MSYS2

In the bullet3-2.83.7 directory (tar.gz from https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/releases)

```
mkdir build-mingw64
cd build-mingw64
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=0 \
    -DBUILD_EXTRAS=1 \
    -DINSTALL_LIBS=0 \
    -DUSE_GLUT=1 \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-fpermissive -g" \
    -DINSTALL_EXTRA_LIBS=0 \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
make -j
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. In my case, it was because Bullet was compiled with USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION, so adding the following to cmakelists for my executable fixed the issue for me:

```
target_compile_options(<target_name> BEFORE PUBLIC -DBT_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION)
```